# Consulta de fecha actual con postgresql (TIMESTAMPZ)

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una consulta en una tabla de pagos (payments) en la cual necesito ver los pagos activos pero con la fecha actual en donde tengo una consulta con los pagos activos:

```
SELECT id 
FROM $this->table 
WHERE canceled = FALSE AND 
      client = :client AND 
      type != 'cancelPay' AND 
      created_at = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Lo que pasa es que me produce un error en *created_at* ya que el dato *created_at* es de tipo TIMESTAMPZ.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece tiene que ser así `CONVERT(DATE,created_at)= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())`

Comment: Mencionás un error: ¿y el error? Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo a tu pregunta, _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

En `postgresql`, puedes hacer un `cast` explícito al tipo de dato de la tabla:

```
SELECT id 
FROM $this->table 
WHERE canceled = FALSE AND 
      client = :client AND 
      type != 'cancelPay' AND 
      created_at = timestamp NOW()
```

Notas:

- `getdate()` no existe en esta base de dato pero tienes `NOW()`.
- No estoy seguro que esto te traiga datos: `created_at = timestamp NOW()`, difícilmente coincida el dato con el `NOW()`